# How to Find Collision Detection between CCSprits?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I am trying to find collision detection between Two Sprits ( encircle with black color in below picture)

here is the code from which i m trying to find with the help by compairing x cordinate of both sprits but unsuccessful

have a look and tell me what is the mistake

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {


    NSLog(@"Target y %f, player y %f",target.position.y, player.position.y);
    if(target.position.y==player.position.y)
//          if((target.position.x==player.position.x)&&(target.position.y==player.position.y))
//  if((sprite.position.y==player.position.y)||(sprite.position.y==player.position.y))
    {
                 Nslog (@"Matched");
            //do Something  
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CCNode class which is the parent of the CCSprite class has a boundingBox property of type CGRect.  Using this property of the player and target objects you can check for collisions using...

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, target.boundingBox) {
    // Kaboom...
}
```

Comment: you can also write somthing like this, it will also calculate if there are any rotations or the ancher point is moved:

    `if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, target.boundingBox) 
    {    
        // Kaboom...
    }`

Comment: well i am getting an error on player.size.width , player.size.height error is : Request for member 'width' in something not a structure Or union

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look at CGRectIntersectsRect like shown here
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-2-user-interaction-simple-ai-game-logic/